# Linking C and C++ object files

Tags: c++, c, linker, ld, object-files

I have the following setup:

main.c:

```
extern void sol();
int main(){
    sol();
}
```

sol.cc:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
void sol(){
    cout<<"HW!!\n";
}
```

I compile to separate object files:

```
$gcc main.c -c
$g++ sol.cc -c
```

But when I try to link them to a single executable,

```
$g++ main.o sol.o
```

I get: `main.c:(.text+0x7): undefined reference to 'sol'` , `nm sol.o` shows that there is `00000000 T _Z3solv` , while `nm main.o` requires `U sol`. I found out that C++ renames functions to avoid same names of overloaded functions. Is there any way to tell compiler that `sol.o` contains renamed functions, or to compile `sol.cc` without renaming them?

Comment: I think that extern "C" would prevent the rename from happening. ie. extern "C" void sol(){cout<<"HW!!\n";}

Comment: `extern "C"` http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compatibility_of_C_and_C%2B%2B#Linking_C_and_C.2B.2B_code

Comment: It is generally best in a mixed C and C++ program to make the `main()` function a C++ function, even if it consists of `int main(int argc, char **argv) { return c_main(argc, argv); }` in its entirety (with a declaration equivalent to `extern "C" int c_main(int argc, char **argv);` in scope).  The original C `main()` is simply renamed to `c_main()` — or `real_main()` or any other name that takes your fancy.

Answer (score 4):

```
extern "C" void sol()
{
    cout<<"HW!!\n";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to use the `extern "C"` declaration to make `sol` available to C. Put this into a common header:

```
extern "C" void sol();
```

Comment: If you want a common header, you'll need to mess around with `#ifdef __cplusplus`, since `extern "C"` isn't valid in C.